# Visual Studio 2010 does not reload open files

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Prior to today, if I quit VS2010 and reopened it, my previously opened solution was loaded and any previously opened files were reloaded and displayed in their correct positions.

Now however, the solution is reopened but no files are reloaded. All the files I had open are closed.

I didn't change any settings or do anything specific to stop this behavior. Looking through the options dialog panels, I do not see anything that applies to this behavior.

What gives?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Resetting VS2010 settings (in Tools choose Import and Export Settings) and deleting the suo file fixed the issue.

Comment: Yep, this fixed it for me as well, thanks. I would love to know what the cause is!

Comment: It's not (just) the suo file - it happened in all my solutions. But a reset did fix it (now I have to find out what settings were changed :-( )

Answer (score 36):

This happened to me as well, but I didn't want to reset all my settings.  So here are a couple things to try before that:

1. Export your settings (Tools -> Import and Export Settings) and open the resulting file in a text editor.  Search for a section starting with `<Category name="Environment_WindowLayout"`.  In my file, there were two places with a riduculous amount of duplicate `<ViewBookmark` entries.  I deleted all but one in both places then I imported this file into VS and it fixed it for me.  Note: I re-imported everything.
2. Along the same lines as above, I read a post about exporting your current settings and then importing the resulting file but excluding window layouts (All Settings -> General Settings -> Window Layouts).

Comment: #1 worked for me but no need to export/import.  Just edit the settings in your Documents\Visual Studio\Settings folder.  I deleted all the ViewBookmark tags using this regex: <ViewBookmark(.|\s)*?>

Comment: This is a little old, but the `ViewBookmark` tags were definitely the issue. In my case, all of the duplicates were generated by Document Well in the Productivity Power Tools add-on. I went through and deleted all of the `ViewBookmark` tags where `ViewBookmarkType="DocumentWell"` and it worked perfectly (simply disabling Docment Well in the Power Tools options will not work).

Comment: I used the XML code formatting tool to fix this.  Export your settings in case anything goes wrong, then open your Documents/Visual Studio/CurrentSettings.vssettings file in VS, hit your format code key (mine is Ctrl-K, Ctrl-D), Select All text, Copy.  Then quit VS, re-open the file in Notepad (remember VS will overwrite this file upon exit so you can't change it in VS), Select All, Paste, Save.

Comment: I was afraid of resetting all settings. So I simply removed all `ViewBookmarks` of type `"DocumentWell"` just like valverij suggested. Works perfectly!

Comment: Perfect! My VS was using 25% of my CPU all the time and doing this solved it!

Comment: This also works in VS 2015.  I just solved the problem myself with this fix.

Answer (score 5):

You may have somehow lost your `.suo` file. Did you move your solution or anything?

Comment: Nothing. Shutdown last night and started up this morning. I deleted my suo file in an attempt to fix the problem. I did notice that about ten windows updates were applied.

Answer (score 1):

Resetting VS2010 General settings (in Tools choose Import and Export Settings) and deleting the suo file, while the project has been opened, fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I tried everything described above but in the end it was doing a full reset in VS2010 General settings (in Tools choose Import and Export Settings) that sorted me out ;-(

Answer (score 1):

To confirm answers that HiredMind and valverij have contributed - I opened a previously exported settings file in VS 2013, executed Edit -> Advanced -> Format Document, then searched for and deleted all of the ViewBookmark tags where ViewBookmarkType="DocumentWell".  I then saved, closed and imported that settings file.  It worked!  VS now (again) reopens the previously opened documents when I open a solution.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I, too, tried editing my .vssettings file.  I deleted a lot but was afraid to delete too much.  What worked for me was to copy an old .vssettings file and use that instead of the recent one.