# Asp.net MVC View slow preformance issue

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-4

I am having some trouble when I am trying to some razor and html code inside my MVC Views. Visual studio keeps hanging and not responding. When entering a simple  tag it can take a few mins to appear. It seems to be a performance issue with asp.net views.

The problem only occurs when inside the views. when coding in the model and the controller I don't have any of the issues.

I am using Visual Studio 2010. Even at home on a better spec machine I have the same issue only the view run really slow.

Has anyone else noticed any performance issues when trying to develop a asp.net MVC 4 view?

Is there any fixes out there for this.

Comment: See [ASP.NET MVC3 Razor views - extremely slow editing in VS2010](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7254325/asp-net-mvc3-razor-views-extremely-slow-editing-in-vs2010), [Visual Studio Debugging/Loading Very Slow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12567984/visual-studio-debugging-loading-very-slow).

Comment: I have tried all answers in that question with no success

Comment: Is your problem specific to a one particular solution, or do you experiencing the same issue in any ASP.NET MVC application with Razor views?

Comment: All solutions even ones i download