# Visual Studio 2012 doesn't open previously opened file when after starting

Tags: visual-studio-2012

This is the default behavior in VS2010. However, after I installed VS2012, I noticed it doesn't open those files I opened last time. Although in the Solution Explorer it remembers my last position, which projects are collapsed, but no file is opened in the editor area after I open the solution. I can't find such setting in opitons. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Possibly the same answer(s) as for VS2010 works for VS2012 as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4963464/visual-studio-2010-does-not-reload-open-files

Comment: Possible duplicate of [visual studio not remembering open documents & startup project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6715594/visual-studio-not-remembering-open-documents-startup-project)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try deleting the `.suo-file` (same folder as `.sln-File`). May fix the problem. Make also sure that you have writing-permissions for `.suo-file`.