# Visual Studio 2008 does not reload open files, but only for one particular solution

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I have run into a strange phenomena using Visual Studio 2008. Usually when I close a Solution then re-open it, the files that were opened when closing the Solution are re-loaded. This works for all my Solution files... except one. I have searched SO for relevant questions, and found these: [Visual Studio 2010 does not reload open files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4963464/visual-studio-2010-does-not-reload-open-files) and [My open documents(tabs) keep disappearing in VS2010 SP1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5340889/my-open-documentstabs-keep-disappearing-in-vs2010-sp1) but none of the suggestions worked for me. I have tried the following:

- Delete the .suo file (even multiple times)
- Searched the registry for the name of the .sln file, in case something interesting turns up (didn't turn up)
- Export and re-import settings while unchecking the Window Layout checkbox
- Remove the Environment_WindowLayout section from the vssettings file
- Reset VS2008 via devenv.exe /resetsettings
- Move the solution to an alternate location
- Create a new solution file from scratch, then re-import the existing .vcproj files

None of these seems to work. When closing the solution which contains ~25 C++ projects, none of the currently opened files are re-opened when re-opening the solution. This doesn't happen with another solution which contains 45 C# projects. I have copied over these solutions to my laptop, and it doesn't manifest this problem. In fact only one machine ever has shown this issue, the one I'm currently working with in the office; not even my co-workers machines.

Visual Studio version number is Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 (Version 9.0.30729.1 SP) professional, with only AnkhSVN 2.4.x used as an extension. The machines in the office I've experimented with have the exact same software. Re-installing VS2008 is acceptable (although I would like to avoid it), upgrading to VS2010 is not possible.

Is there a way to explain and/or fix this behaviour?

Comment: The windows layout is saved in the .suo file.  You've whacked it several times already so that leaves you without another paddle.  You'd normally file a bug report at Connect, but there's no point in doing this for such an old VS version.

Comment: @HansPassant: yes, I'm afraid so.